# SQL - avoid repeated column values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT t.id, apa.district AS district
FROM tbl_activity AS t
JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap ON ap.activity_id = t.id
JOIN tbl_activity_package_address AS apa ON apa.activity_package_id = ap.id
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY apa.district
```

After querying, the output is:

[image: output]

I want to return only one row by district. How can I do that in the query?

Comment: Specify `DISTINCT` (also do not select `id` with district then since `<117, Evora>` __is not__ same as `<118, Evora>`)

Comment: Do you care which `id` value is returned alongside "Evora"?

Comment: @AlmaDo `DISTINCT` doesn't change anything.

Comment: You need to choose one, or drop id from the result set and use distinct

Comment: Isn't there a way to to that with id? I will need it because in the original code, there is a `*`, which is essential.

Comment: There is, but you need to define which id you want, when there are multiple id values for the same district.

Comment: @PatrickQ There is the possibility to exist more than one district to the same id and more than one id to one district. So here is the whole problem: I just want one district by id and vice versa.

Comment: First, your question states "I want to return only one row by district". If that is not accurate, then you should clarify. Second, "more than one district to the same id" is possibly (although not necessarily) indicative of poor DB design. You should explain what each of those tables represents so we have a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You want to group by `district`, rather than by `id`.

However, this leaves you with a dilema: which `id` value do you want to show for the Evora district? Do you want the 117 id, or the 118 id? How will you determine it? You need a specific rule for which one you want. As an example, this will give you the larger:

```
SELECT MAX(t.id) id, apa.district AS district
FROM tbl_activity AS t
JOIN tbl_activity_package AS ap ON ap.activity_id = t.id
JOIN tbl_activity_package_address AS apa ON apa.activity_package_id = ap.id
GROUP BY apa.district
ORDER BY apa.district
```

Changing MAX() to MIN() will give you the lower id. You can have more complicated criteria as well, but those require first building this as derived table (sub query) that you can join against to map your criteria to a specific id number.

Comment: Certainly good information, but I don't feel like the OP has provided enough detail (yet) to say that this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @JoelCoehoorn. But if I change the `GROUP BY` clause, as you did, I get another row of id 98.

Comment: @felipe.zkn then the table design is broken, or the join conditions are incomplete